# getting the local system date time and converting it to a string (MFC C++)

Tags: c++, string, mfc, strcpy, systemtime

I have inherited some MFC C++ code (it's an ActiveX OCX control running on a Windows Mobile 6.5 device)  and I need to acquire the system date and time and append it as part of an existing string which gets passed via the com port to another device.

I can get the system date and time, but I can not figure out how to convert that into a string so that I can append it (via strcat.)

I've found a number of different answers on Google and Bing for what at first glance seemed like such a simple problem... :(  but I don't know enough MFC C++ to adapt any of it to my needs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
CTime t = CTime::GetCurrentTime();
CString s = t.Format( "%A, %B %d, %Y" );
char * str = (LPCTSTR) s;
```

Note, I believe that `str` is only valid while `s` is in scope. Probably should copy it off somewhere if you need it to be around after `s` is destroyed. If you are passing it to `strcat()` you're probably OK.

Answer (score 1):

In MFC the following code is for current date in MMDDYYYY format.

```
CTime t = CTime::GetCurrentTime();
CString strDate = t.Format("%m%d%Y");
```